# VSCode complains a Ruby UTF-8 file has invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, visual-studio-code

Using Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.3 (ruby files by default are UTF-8).

If I check the file in the terminal:

```
 file -I <filename>.rb
```

it shows UTF-8:

```
<filename>.rb: text/x-ruby; charset=utf-8
```

Yet in the file there is a string with a German umlaut character as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

In pre v2.0 of Ruby you could use [magic comments](https://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/58-magic-instructions.html) to tell Ruby the files encoding, but obviously this file is already UTF-8.

What I am trying to figure out is 2 things:

1. How did a UTF-8 file get this US-ASCII character inside it?
2. How can I fix it (so VS-Code is not showing it as incorrect)? I wonder if perhaps something to do with an extension or setting in VS-Code?.

In answer to (1) I am guessing it was perhaps copy and pasted from a file that was encoded US-ASCII (like Word)?

However if I delete the character and type it again on my Mac using OPT + u + u then VS Code still complains. Hence question 2.

With regard to (2) I checked this:

```
echo LC_TYPE
```

and it was null.

So I added `export LC_TYPE=$LANG` to my `~/.bash-profile` and restarted VSCode, but that did not solve it (and in the VSCode integrated terminal LC_TYPE is still null). [Ref](https://github.com/castwide/vscode-solargraph/issues/37#issuecomment-404122975)

***EDIT***

There is no need to answer question 1, because if I delete the character and retype it, the same error shows up. So I now know it doesn't really matter how it got into the file, just need to know what is producing the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is in the linter.

```
"ruby.lint": {
       "reek": true,
       "rubocop": true,
       "ruby": {
         "unicode": true,
       },
       "fasterer": true,
       "debride": false,
       "ruby-lint": false
   },
```

in **settings.json** **unicode** is not **turned on** by default for ruby.lint so you need to do that manually.